# Are there any exceptions to the upper and lower bounds theorem?

Tags: algebra-precalculus, polynomials, upper-lower-bounds

Hi there :) I'm new to this site so please let me know if there's anything wrong with my question.

I was trying to find the roots of the polynomial expression $P(x) = 8x^5 - 14x^4 - 22x^3 +57x^2 - 35x + 6$. I first found $(x+2)$ using the Rational Zeros Theorem and synthetic division. Since the result of $\frac{P(x)}{x+2}$ is $Q(x) = 8x^4 - 30x^3 + 38x^2 - 19x + 3$, I assumed $-2$ is a lower bound, because of the alternating signs. And from the graph I can see that's true, since there are no x-intercepts smaller than $-2$.

[graph of P(x)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IMTMo.png)

Then, I found $(x - 1)$ as a root. The result $\frac{Q(x)}{x-1} = 8x^3-22x^2+16x-3 = R(x)$ implies that, according to the theorem, 1 is a lower bound of $Q(x)$, but this time, according to the graph, that is not true. I supposed that roots themselves cannot be considered upper and lower bounds.

[graph of Q(x)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hgI3l.png)

However, when dividing $R(x)$ by $(x-1)$ I get $8x^2-14x+2 - \frac{1}{x-1}$, which is not a root, but should be a lower bound according to the theorem, and that does not make sense looking at the graph.

[graph of R(x)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/j2GRk.png)

Am I doing something wrong? Or maybe this is indeed an exception to the theorem? Also, can you tell me whether roots can or cannot be considered as bounds themselves?

Thank you in advance! :)

Edit: I first uploaded the wrong graph of Q(x). Thanks to Noah Schweber for letting me know!

Comment: Thank you for your answer!
a) Oh man, you're right! I tend to make mistakes when entering polynomials into the calculator or an app. But the correct graph still shows there are roots smaller than 1. I'll edit my post not to confuse other people.

b) That's something new to me. I thought you could apply the lower-upper bound test with the synthetic divison to any polynomial before knowing whether the divisor is a root or not. So, one can only use it with roots?

c) That makes sense! I should improve my knowledge of proper Math terminology :)

Comment: Wait, no, WolframAlpha is giving me the same graph! I'm entering 8x^4-30x^3+38x^2-19x+3.

Comment: Sorry, I plugged into $R$ instead of $Q$.

Comment: But the graph in your link is R(x), and that's exactly the one I included in my post (as you just wrote hehe... I just read your comment)

Comment: The lower bound theorem requires $c$ to be negative, so $x-1$ isn't a candidate divisor.

Answer (score 1):

The relevant theorem is:

> Suppose $f$ is a polynomial, $c<0$ is a zero of $f$, and the coefficients of the quotient polynomial $f(x)\over x-c$ have alternating signs. Then every zero of $f$ is $\ge c$.

This has two hypotheses on $c$ which must be met: $c$ must be a zero of $f$ and $c$ must be negative. This explains each failure in your question.

Comment: Thank you! Now everything makes sense :) Next time I'll read the whole theorem before applying it.